# Lower bound on absolute smallest root of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, upper-lower-bounds

Given a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_k a_k x^k$ with $x,a_k\in \mathbb{R}$, I am looking for a lower bound on roots $r_i$ of the following kind:

$$
\min_i |r_i| \geq ?
$$

So far, I found this [paper](http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/~gvm/radovi/rad2.pdf) which says (Theorem 2.15):
For $p(x) = \sum_{v=0}^n a_v x^v $ with $a_n=1$ and $A=\max_{0\leq v\leq n-1}|a_v|$, $p(x)$ has all its zeroes in the ring-shaped region:
$$
\frac{|a_0|}{ 2 (1+A)^{n-1} (An+1) } \leq |x| \leq 1 + \lambda_0 A,
$$
where I skipped the $\lambda_0$ part, as I am interested in the left side of the inequality.

The problem with this bound is that it does not seem to be very tight, particularly for high-order polynomials. Therefore, I am asking whether more/tighter bounds are known.